# How to create an Array from Iterable in Scala 2.7.7?

Tags: scala

I'm using **Scala 2.7.7**

I'm experiencing difficulties with access to the documentation, so code snippets would be greate.

**Context**

I parse an IP address of 4 or 16 bytes in length. I need an array of bytes, to pass into java.net.InetAddress. The result of String.split(separator).map(_.toByte) returns me an instance of Iterable.

I see two ways to solve the problem

- use an array of 16 bytes length, fil it from Iterable and return just a part of it, if not all fields are used (Is there a function to fill an array in 2.7.7? How to get the part?).
- use a dynamic length container and form an array form it (Which container is suitable?).

Current implementation is published in [my other question about memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062459/where-is-memory-leak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala 2.7, [`Iterable`](http://scala-tools.org/scaladocs/scala-library/2.7.1/scala/Iterable.html) has a method called `copyToArray`.

Comment: How do I truncate array then, to return only used cells?

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly advise you not to use an Array here, unless you have to use a particular library/framework then requires an array.

Normally, you'd be better off with a native Scala type:

```
String.split(separator).map(_.toByte).toList
//or
String.split(separator).map(_.toByte).toSeq
```

**Update**

Assuming that your original string is a delimited list of hostnames, why not just:

```
val namesStr = "www.sun.com;www.stackoverflow.com;www.scala-tools.com"
val separator = ";"
val addresses = namesStr.split(separator).map(InetAddress.getByName)
```

That'll give you an iterable of `InetAddress` instances.

Comment: java.net.InetAddress.getByAddress(byte[] addr) requires Byte Array